# Edited video produces smaller image that original, even with higher resolution

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, aspect-ratio

I've a .ts format recording from my Humax, which completely fills the window horizontally when played with VLC. In full-screen it fills the screen horizontally in letterbox style, and the same on the TV when played through my PS/3. All good so far.

This is the ffprobe output:

```
Duration: 02:16:37.72, start: 74238.902878, bitrate: 2554 kb/s
Stream #0:0[0x931]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv), 704x576 [SAR 16:11 DAR 16:9], max. 15000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
```

I used ffmpeg to change the audio track:

```
ffmpeg -i movie.ts -c:v libx264 -c:a ac3 -crf 20 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:1 movie.mp4
```

and produced an .mp4 which also plays correctly.

ffprobe:

```
Duration: 02:16:37.68, start: 0.005333, bitrate: 1129 kb/s
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 704x576 [SAR 16:11 DAR 16:9], 932 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
```

However, if I edit it using OpenShot, I cannot find any export format that produces an image that fills the window horizontally in the same way, regardless of what resolution or aspect ratio I use.

Example: export format "DV/DVD Widescreen PAL (720x576)" produces this (sample) file:

```
Duration: 00:00:39.12, start: 0.040000, bitrate: 563 kb/s
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x576, 477 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
```

OpenShot appears not to set the AR, so it initially shows in VLC in 5:4 aspect, but even changing the VLC AR to the maximum of 2.39:1 does not stretch it fully from side-to-side.

I've used ffmpeg to experiment with changing the aspect ratio, changing the resolution, and setting the SAR and DAR, all without success.

This can't be a resolution issue, as I've exported 720p and 1080i, plenty of pixels but all produce roughly the same result - a small image that doesn't fill the window, and ditto on the TV. The original recording is only 704x576 but fills the window. Also the aspect ratio of the original recording is 16:9 (VLC agrees) but the actual measured AR of the screen image is closer to 2.04:1.

I'm hoping that while this could be an OpenShot issue, the cause of the problem should be visible to ffprobe and perhaps fixable with ffmpeg. Help wil be appreciated.

Comment: Did you tried with other programs (to view output)? 720x576 cannot fill a screen: you have much less information. So first program may upscale the output. I would check why it would not upscale the mangled video.

Comment: Xplayer (Linux) gives the same result as VLC. SD broadcast content fills the screen on an HD TV, just at lower quality, so lack of pixels can't be the issue. The original recording fills the screen, I just can't persuade the edited version to do the same.